# Módulo Delphi para Apache 32 bits com erro

Tags: delphi, apache, rest

Estou utilizando o Apache para subir um servidor rest feito em Delphi, quando gero o modulo no Delphi na versão 32 bits, coloco na pasta de modules do Apache e o executo simplesmente dá erro e não inicia o Apache, já a versão 64 bits funciona normalmente. Testado no win 7 32 e 64.

Edit: Eu criei um servidor datasnap webbroker e escolhi a opção de Apache dynamic link module, fiz as funções que preciso buscar do banco de dados, até ai tudo certo. Instalei o apache na maquina 32 bits, funcionando corretamente, quando coloco a dll gerada pelo delphi na pasta modules e coloco o LoadModule no arquivo httpd.conf e inicio o apache ele simplesmente da erro e não inicia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta e mostre um pouco do que fez. Dessa forma esta muito ampla/não esta clara suficiente.

Comment: Ja esta explicado, a própria exceção te mostrou a resposta, uma DLL no Delphi para Apache deve conter apenas 1 DataModule.

Comment: Mas o estranho que funciona na versão 64 bits com o mesmo código

Comment: Júnior Moreira, seria bom colocar seu comentário como resposta para ser votada como a solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, graças ao Júnior Moreira e algumas pesquisas achei em um fórum algo relacionado. Tive que bloquear a criação automática do DataModule e criar manualmente. 
Segue o link abaixo caso alguém precise.

https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/144990-resolvido%C2%A0intraweb-data-module/

Segue na imagem o que fiz para resolver o problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Matheus, consegue colocar um "snippet" do seu código na sua resposta? Assim ela fica mais completa e mais fácil de localizar para futuras referências (caso o link saia do ar, por exemplo)